# jQuery.validate with custom errors per control

Tags: jquery, metadata

I'm currently using jQuery.validate as a plugin for validation... my problem comes into play where I want to use custom error messages based on the validation type per control.

I'm using the metadata extension for this, and I've thought about just having a generic formatter that gets passed in.. so the error message is literally "{0}" and when I specify my validators, I can do so inline...

```
<input ... data-meta='{
    validate: {
       date: [ "real error message here" ]
    }
}' />
```

With myDate defined as...

```
// override default date...
$.validator.addMethod("date", function(value, element) { 
    //use Date.js's parse instead of default's new Date() matching.
    return this.optional(element) || !!Date.parse(value);
}, "{0}");
```

I can't help but to feel a little "dirty" doing this though...  does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata version for validation already has built-in support for messages, for example:

```
<input ... 
 data-meta='{validate:{date:true,messages:{date:"real error message here"}}}' />
```

[You can see it in action in the jQuery validation metadata demo here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/custom-messages-metadata-demo.html).

Comment: Thanks, actually had figured it out... Spent so much time yesterday working on binding in custom events for specific points in the validation... "validation.beforestart" (can stop validation), "validation.errors", "validation.success" etc.. so I can do all forms consistently but wire in extra handling after the fact.  Would be nice if the validator did these as part of the internal submit handling.

Comment: Please beware of HTML5 related issues, as noted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105959/jquery-validate-jquery-metadata-and-html5-data